# How can I determine why my mobile .net application is freezing after the device awakes from sleep mode?

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, compact-framework

I have a .net compact mobile application (device OS is windows mobile 6.0 using sdk 2.0) running on a Motorola device.

If the application is running and I leave the device alone for about 20 minutes it will be in sleep mode.  Sometimes, after I wake it by tapping the power button, the device wakes up fine, but my application is frozen, unresponsive. I can still see the last form page I was on, but I can't do anything with it.

The rest of the device is responsive, though.  Even trying to to close the application from task manager fails.  The application remains "active" in the frozen state.

Is there any way I can diagnose this? Like, is there any special way I can log this problem or find out via the device what happened?

Comment: Not a mobile developer, but can't you attach a debugger to the frozen app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple, direct way, no.  The device comes out of suspend and resumes processing code where it left off.  If your app is freezing, it could be that it's waiting on some handle that's been invalidated by the suspend/resume cycle, but really the only way to find it is to try a twofold approach:

1. Instrument the code with logging so when it freezes you can narrow down the "where" in the code it's happening.
2. At the same time, remove functionality (services, threads, whatever your code base allows) to further reduce the tested function set.  If you remove a feature and the problem goes away, you know where to look.  If it doesn't go away, you've eliminated that whole branch of code from needed further inspection.